# Why I have to call delete on the "original" pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, delete-operator

I would like to know why in the following code the first delete won't free the memory:

```
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc {
    long a;

    abc() {
        puts("const");
    }
    ~abc() {
        puts("desc");
    }
};

int main() {

    std::list<abc*> test;

    abc* pA = new abc;
    printf("pA: 0x%lX\n", (unsigned long int)pA);
    test.push_back(pA);

    abc* pB = test.back();

    printf("pB: 0x%lX\n", (unsigned long int)pB);
    delete pB; // just ~abc()

    test.pop_back();

    delete pA; // ~abc() and free (works)

    puts("before double-free");

    delete pA; // ~abc() and second free (crash)

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
const
pA: 0x93D8008
pB: 0x93D8008
desc
desc
before double-free
desc
*** glibc detected *** ./test: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x093d8008 ***
...
```

I tried it with `free()` also but same behavior.

Comment: You are deleting the same object 3 times? For every `new` you should have **one** delete.

Comment: "why in the following code the first delete wont free the memory" - it does.

Comment: The memory is freed just fine... the *first* time.

Comment: @ronag: As an exception to the rule: Except when you store the new'd stuff in a smart pointer.

Comment: @phresnel: Indeed, then the delete is done by the smart-pointer. So a better definition would be, "Except when someone else deletes".

Comment: @ronag: That's a good generalisation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete pA; // ~abc() and free (works)

puts("before double-free");

delete pA; // ~abc() and second free (crash)
```

These `delete` statements are **not** needed once you write `delete pB`. You've a misconception that `delete pB` only calls the destructor. No, it calls the destructor and also deallocates the memory.

Also, since you've already written `delete pB`, the next two further `delete` expressions invoke [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means anything can happen : the program *may* or *may not* crash!

Have a look at these topics:

- [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)
- [Is there any way to predict the undefined behaviour or implementation defined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811803/is-there-any-way-to-predict-the-undefined-behaviour-or-implementation-defined-be)
- [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-ab)

Comment: I know but if there is double-free, program should crash but it won't.

Comment: @quarry: Why do you think it should crash?  It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @quarry: No, if you try to free something that is already freed you invoke Undefined Behavior. The program may crash, or print a message, or it may cause demons to fly out of your nose.

Comment: @quarry: See my answer again. I also answered that part.

Comment: @Nawaz I already read it. Every time I did something like double-free program crashed but I know that its not 100%. Now I have now other opinion. Thanks, this makes my problem clear.

Comment: @Nawaz: "anything can happen" is of course true by the standard, but given that glibc detects a double free on the third `delete`, I'm interested why it fails to detect it on the second `delete`. Is it an essential shortcoming of the safety measures in glibc, a bug in the detection code, or just lack of aggression to find as many such problems as possible, and what's the difference that matters between the two calls? glibc has its own requirements beyond those of the standard, and we can expect comprehensible behavior even though we aren't guaranteed it.

Comment: @SteveJessop : See my answer ... apparently there is some platform/compiler idiosyncrasies in-play here ... Since as has been pointed out, this is all undefined behavior, I'm guessing that there are some differences on each platform for how checking the state of a double-free is done.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You can set the environment variable `MALLOC_CHECK_` to make glibc use a less efficient error checking implementation instead of the default. setting this to 3 should make the program print a message to stderr and promptly `abort()` for double `free()` and similar cases.

Comment: @Hasturkun: ah, so double-free detection is actually switched off here, but the second free causes some corruption that (on this occasion) is detected when the third free is attempted?

Comment: @SteveJessop: The default implementation does internal sanity/consistency checks in general. The error checking implementation adds additional checks around allocation calls to detect (and possibly ignore/survive) some measure of heap corruption (eg. using a magic value to detect `free` after writing one off the end of an allocated buffer, or freeing an invalid pointer)

Answer (score 2):

Your first delete renders the pointer to invalid state. So use of that pointer now leads to undefined behaviour.

```
int* p = new int;
delete p;
delete p; //undefined behaviour
```

This is guaranteed to be fine by the standard (as pointed out in the first comment):

```
int* p = new int;
delete p;
p = 0;
delete p; //fine
```

Comment: Your second snippet is guaranteed fine by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't `free` memory allocated with `new`, you have to use `delete`.

Secondly, just because glibc doesn't detect the double free immediately, how do you **know** `delete pB;` isn't freeing it?  That's what `delete` does, and from your own logging you're passing the same address to `delete` each time.

Thirdly: what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

It's just an indiosyncracy of your compiler/platform that you had to call `delete` twice on `pA` before `glibc` complained ... for instance, on my current platform, which is OSX 10.6.8 with `gcc` version i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1, I get the following output:

```
const
pA: 0x100100080
pB: 0x100100080
desc
desc
test(14410) malloc: *** error for object 0x100100080: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

So you can see the first call to `delete` on `pA`, which by the standard results in undefined behavior since you didn't set the pointer to `NULL` or `0`, did get caught as an attempt to deallocate already deallocated memory by the C++ run-time on my platform.

Since the results of the double-delete are "undefined behavior", it's really up to the implementation and platform on what happens.

You may be able to detect allocation/deallocation memory errors quicker if you use the link against the glibc memory consistency checker by compiling with the `-lmcheck` flag.